# Problem with std::stable_sort after g++ 9.1 update

Tags: c++, g++, c++17, std

After updating from gcc/g++ **8.1** to **9.1** and recompiling my code, most of its tests failed. Hence, a little digging was made and I have found out that [`std::stable_sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort) was the problem.

As it turns out, most calls of my calls to `std::stable_sort` were not necessary, that is, calling [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) would be enough. Thus, I have done the substitution where it was possible, and the tests regarding these pieces of code succeed again.

Now, I have only one call to `std::stable_sort`

```
void MshReader::determinePhysicalEntitiesRange() {
    // conns is not empty

    std::stable_sort(this->conns.begin(), this->conns.end(), 
        [=](const auto& a, const auto& b){
            return a[this->index] < b[this->index];
        }
    );

    // acess some values of conns
}
```

Where *conns* is a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` that stores element connectivities. The sorting is done based on column *index*, its value is assigned in the class header, and all `std::vector<int>` in *conns* have that entry.

Another fact worth mentioning is that, on **debug** builds (compiler flag "-g" is used, "-O3" is NOT) **all tests succeed**.

Also, on **release** builds (flag "-O3" is used, "-g" is NOT), by printing the values of *conns* before and after the call to `std::stable_sort`, I have discovered that *conns* is ruined.

Before

```
row:
  0:    0   2   0   1
  1:    0   2   1   2
  2:    0   1   2   5
  3:    0   1   5   8
  4:    0   3   8   7
  5:    0   3   7   6
  6:    0   0   6   3
  7:    0   0   3   0
  8:    1   4   3   4   9
  9:    1   4   3   9   6
 10:    1   4   4   7   9
 11:    1   4   6   9   7
 12:    1   4   1   2  10
 13:    1   4   1  10   4
 14:    1   4   2   5  10
 15:    1   4   4  10   5
 16:    2   4   4   5   8   7
 17:    2   4   0   1   4   3
```

After

```
row:
  0:    0   0   6   3
  1:    0   0   3   0
  2:    0   1   2   5
  3:    0   1   5   8
  4:    0   2   1   2 // there were two rows with column 'index' = 2
  5:    0   3   8   7
  6:    0   3   7   6
  7:    1   4   2   5  10  10  10  10 // this entry was previously on row 14; extra '10's
  8:    1   4   3   4   9
  9:    1   4   3   9   6
 10:    1   4   4   7   9
 11:    1   4   6   9   7
 12:    1   4   1   2  10
 13:    1   4   1  10   4
 14:    1   4   2   5  10
 15:    1   4   4  10   5
 16:    2   4   4   5   8   7
 17:    2   4   0   1   4   3
```

On **debug** builds, `std::stable_sort` outputs the expected result. Besides that, `c++17` is being used (compiler flag "-std=c++17").

Therefore,

- Is something wrong with my call to `std::stable_sort`?
- Which changes on g++ led to this behavior?
- Why this behavior only appears in **release** builds?

**Minimal Example**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename InputIt>
void print2D(InputIt cbegin, InputIt cend, std::string&& message) {
    std::cout << message;
    for (auto i = cbegin; i != cend; ++i) {
        for (auto j = i->cbegin(); j != i->cend(); ++j) {
            std::cout << "\t" << std::setw(3) << std::right << *j;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    int index = 1;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> conns{{0,2,0,1},{0,2,1,2},{0,1,2,5},{0,1,5,8},{0,3,8,7},{0,3,7,6},{0,0,6,3},{0,0,3,0},{1,4,3,4,9},{1,4,3,9,6},{1,4,4,7,9},{1,4,6,9,7},{1,4,1,2,10},{1,4,1,10,4},{1,4,2,5,10},{1,4,4,10,5},{2,4,4,5,8,7},{2,4,0,1,4,3}};

    print2D(conns.cbegin(), conns.cend(), "\n\n\tbefore\n");

    std::stable_sort(conns.begin(), conns.end(), 
        [=](const auto& a, const auto& b){
            return a[index] < b[index];
        }
    );

    print2D(conns.cbegin(), conns.cend(), "\n\n\tafter\n");

    return 0;
}
```

If the above is compiled with

```
    g++ -o main main.cpp -m64 -std=c++17 -O3
```

It outputs `segmentation fault (core dumped)`. However, if the flag "-O3" is not employed, the expected results is obtained.

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve], please?

Comment: Of course. An (almost) minimal example has been provided - it compiles with g++ 9.1

Comment: Adding `-fsanitize=undefined` stops it from crashing for me :-) Valgrind (without `-fsanitize=undefined`) gives [this](https://pastebin.com/QWp977sB)

Comment: Filed [91007](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=91007)

Comment: @Barry Nice, that's what I call a minimal example :-)

Comment: Aside: the `-g` flag is completely irrelevant, all that matters is the optimisation flags. Enabling debug info in "release" builds still works with GCC and doesn't affect the generated code at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first "`b`" that, when compiled with g++ 9.1.1, is passed into the lambda has `size()==0` which should be impossible. clang++ 8.0.0 runs it without problems using the same compilation flags and does not show anything strange when running `valgrind`.

I'd say it's a bug in g++. Code with debug output in the lambda function:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename InputIt>
void print2D(InputIt cbegin, InputIt cend, const std::string&& message) {
    std::cout << message;
    for(auto i = cbegin; i != cend; ++i) {
        for(auto j : *i) {
            std::cout << "\t" << std::setw(3) << std::right << j;
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main() {
    size_t index = 1;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> conns{
        {0, 2, 0, 1},       {0, 2, 1, 2},      {0, 1, 2, 5},     {0, 1, 5, 8},
        {0, 3, 8, 7},       {0, 3, 7, 6},      {0, 0, 6, 3},     {0, 0, 3, 0},
        {1, 4, 3, 4, 9},    {1, 4, 3, 9, 6},   {1, 4, 4, 7, 9},  {1, 4, 6, 9, 7},
        {1, 4, 1, 2, 10},   {1, 4, 1, 10, 4},  {1, 4, 2, 5, 10}, {1, 4, 4, 10, 5},
        {2, 4, 4, 5, 8, 7}, {2, 4, 0, 1, 4, 3}};

    print2D(conns.cbegin(), conns.cend(), "\n\n\tbefore\n");

    std::stable_sort(conns.begin(), conns.end(), [=](const auto& a, const auto& b) {
        std::cout << index << "\ta.size=" << a.size() << " b.size=" << b.size() << "\n";
        return a[index] < b[index];
    });

    print2D(conns.cbegin(), conns.cend(), "\n\n\tafter\n");
}
```

Output:

```
   before
     0    2     0   1
     0    2     1   2
     0    1     2   5
     0    1     5   8
     0    3     8   7
     0    3     7   6
     0    0     6   3
     0    0     3   0
     1    4     3   4    9
     1    4     3   9    6
     1    4     4   7    9
     1    4     6   9    7
     1    4     1   2   10
     1    4     1  10    4
     1    4     2   5   10
     1    4     4  10    5
     2    4     4   5    8      7
     2    4     0   1    4      3

1  a.size=4 b.size=0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: A godbolt-version shows the same thing: https://godbolt.org/z/EKIk_f and when changing to g++ 8.3, it looks alright: https://godbolt.org/z/Nkgz2I

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Should one always pass `-fsanitize=undefined` to gcc/g++ in order to prevent similar issues?

Comment: @FelipeGiacomelli I always use it when developing. It's supposed to help me find bugs in _my_ code, not hide bugs in the toolchain :-) So, no, don't count on it to fix issues like this. It's not what it's there for and the fact that it had this effect is a bit strange.